# create a pipe for several processes

Tags: bash, pipe

I try to pipe several scripts, but dont really understand how to do it correctly.

```
  mkfifo pipe1
  cat ./script1 > pipe1 &
  cat ./script2 > pipe1 &
  cat ./script3 > pipe1 &
 ./script1 < pipe1
```

So the question is can I do it thay way? I mean to write all scripts in one pipe and read just one of the when I need it

Comment: Why are you not just passing `script1, script2, script3` as arguments to `videoplaylist` if you are simply dumping them to `stdout`?

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail on your task? What are the processes supposed to do? The code you wrote looks... unusual :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Answer for Original Question

`cat` can handle multiple files and will read each in turn:

```
cat ./script1 ./script2 ./script3 | ./videoplaylist
```

**Update:**  In the revised version of the question, the target is `script1` itself:

```
cat ./script1 ./script2 ./script3 | ./script1
```

### Answer for Revised Question

The following code will run three scripts, merge their output and send it to `masterscript`:

```
mkfifo pipe1
bash ./script1 > pipe1 &
bash ./script2 > pipe1 &
bash ./script3 > pipe1 &
bash ./masterscript < pipe1
```

#### Working Example

Let's start with four scripts:

```
$ cat script1
#!/bin/sh
while sleep 1;do echo $0 $(date); done
$ cat script2
#!/bin/sh
$ cat masterscript 
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do echo "$0 received: $line"; done
while sleep 1;do echo $0 $(date); done
$ cat script3
#!/bin/sh
while sleep 1;do echo $0 $(date); done
```

Now let's execute them:

```
$ mkfifo pipe1
$ bash script1 >pipe1 & bash script2 >pipe1 & bash script3 >pipe1 &
[1] 29154
[2] 29155
[3] 29156
$ bash masterscript <pipe11
masterscript received: script2 Sat Apr 11 15:39:37 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script1 Sat Apr 11 15:39:37 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script3 Sat Apr 11 15:39:37 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script2 Sat Apr 11 15:39:38 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script1 Sat Apr 11 15:39:38 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script3 Sat Apr 11 15:39:38 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script1 Sat Apr 11 15:39:39 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script3 Sat Apr 11 15:39:39 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script2 Sat Apr 11 15:39:39 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script1 Sat Apr 11 15:39:40 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script2 Sat Apr 11 15:39:40 PDT 2015
masterscript received: script3 Sat Apr 11 15:39:40 PDT 2015
^C
```

As you can see, the FIFO succeeds in sending output of each the three scripts to the master script.

Comment: remove `./`. it should be `cat script1`

Comment: I want to realize a switch case. So The script1 is  a main script1, the script 2 pauses the script1 and the script3 quits the script1. For example by pressing a button on a keyboard the script1 starts. If I press another button the script2 pauses script1 and so on.  So this one syntax should be correct? ´ cat ./script1 ./script2 ./script3 > pipe1`

Comment: and for case 1 I want to call a script1 with `script1 < pipe`

Comment: @check That changes things entirely.  It sounds now like you want to __execute__ those scripts, not `cat` them.

Comment: @check See updated answer for a working example of three scripts feeding their output, via a FIFO, to a master control script.

Comment: So I dont need to write the masterscript to the FIFO?

Comment: @check Right.  If I correctly understand what you want, masterscript needs  to _read from_ the FIFO, not get written to it.

Comment: Yes master should read the commands from the other scriptes. So the Idea is to call the different scriptes by pushing a button on the keyboard. So If I press 'a' on the keaybord all scriptes are written to the pipe and the masterscript starts. Now If I press 'b' the script1 sends a command to a master. What is the correct syntax for it? This one? : `case "$button" in  a) mkfifo pipe1
bash ./script1 > pipe1 &
bash ./script2 > pipe1 &
bash ./script3 > pipe1 &
bash ./masterscript < pipe1 ;; case b) bash script1 >pipe1`

Comment: or it schould be `case b) bash script1 > pipe1   ./masterscript < pipe1`